# Unique solutions to non-homogeneous equations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, homogeneous-equation

I have two problems that I've been working on, and I want to make sure that my work is correct. I'm simply finding unique solutions to non-homogeneous equations, as shown below.

(1) a<sub>n</sub> - 2a<sub>n - 1</sub> = 5      with a<sub>0</sub> = 1

(2) a<sub>n</sub> - 2a<sub>n - 1</sub> = 2<sup>n</sup> with a<sub>0</sub> = 1

My work:

(1) For our general solution, we use a<sub>n</sub> - 2a<sub>n - 1</sub> = 0.

This gives us r - 2 = 0, where r = 2, and so our root is 2. Our general function is h(n) = k(2)<sup>n</sup> where k is a constant.

Try p(n) = c. So we need p(n) - 2p(n-1) = 5.

c - 2c = 5

-c = 5

c = -5

So our general solution a<sub>n</sub> = h(n) + p(n) is:

a<sub>n</sub> = k(2)<sup>n</sup> + (-5). Our initial condition is a<sub>0</sub> = 1.

1 = k(2)<sup>0</sup> + (-5)

1 = k + (-5).  So our k = 6.

Our unique solution is a<sub>n</sub> = 6(2)<sup>n</sup> + (-5).

(2) The general solution is is the same as above, with root 2 and h(n) = k(2)<sup>n</sup>.

But for p(n), trying c2<sup>n</sup> gives us 0 = 2<sup>n</sup>, and so we add n.

p(n) = cn2<sup>n</sup>

cn2<sup>n</sup> - c(n-1)2<sup>n</sup> = 2<sup>n</sup>

c = 1

So we now have h(n) + p(n) = k(2)<sup>n</sup> + 1.

1 = a<sub>0</sub> = k(2)<sup>0</sup> + 1

1 = k + 1. So our k = 0.
Our unique solution should be:

a<sub>n</sub> = 0(2)<sup>n</sup> + 1.

Answer (score 0):

*You could make life simpler for the first case.*

Consider $$a_n-2a_{n-1}=b\qquad \text{with}\qquad a_1=c$$ and rewrite the recurrence as $$(a_n-b)-2(a_{n-1}-b)=0$$ So, define $d_n=a_n-b$ to get
$$d_n-2d_{n-1}=0\qquad \text{with}\qquad d_1=c+b$$ and you know how to solve it.